# Wordpress Shortcode Issus v2

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a 'Contact Form' shortcode to use in WP. All works fine apart from getting to load on the WordPress site.

[image]

When I copy the [contact_form] into Page or Post and Preview on a Page it prints just text. I did the code right.

```
<?php

class Settings {
      // Conact Form shortcode

    public function allb_contact_form( $atts, $content = null  ) {
          //[contact_form]
          //get the attribute_escape
          $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(),
            $atts,
            'contact_form'
          );
          //return HTML
          ob_start();
          include '/lib/inc/thmeplates/contact-form.php';
          return ob_get_clean();

        add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'allb_contact_form' );
    }

} new Settings();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add_shortcode()` function call needs to refer to the containing class. So if `add_shortcode()` was called from outside the class you need to do.

```
class MyPlugin {    
    public static function baztag_func( $atts, $content = "" ) {           
        return "content = $content";    
    } 
} 
add_shortcode( 'baztag', array( 'MyPlugin', 'baztag_func' ) );
```

That example is from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

If called from within class you refer to the class within itself like so:

```
add_shortcode( 'baztag', array( $this , 'baztag_func' ) );
```

Also, you can't add the shortcode from the same function that outputs the shortcode. So try the following:

```
<?php

class Settings {
      // Conact Form shortcode

    public function __construct(){
        add_shortcode( 'contact_form', array($this , 'allb_contact_form' ));
    }

    public function allb_contact_form( $atts, $content = null  ) {
          //[contact_form]
          //get the attribute_escape
          $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(),
            $atts,
            'contact_form'
          );
          //return HTML
          ob_start();
          include '/lib/inc/thmeplates/contact-form.php';
          return ob_get_clean();             
    }

} new Settings();
```

Comment: When I add the add_shortcode out of the class come up with error messages that says.  Notice: do_shortcode_tag was called incorrectly. Attempting to parse a shortcode without a valid callback: contact_form Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.3.0.) in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/wordpress-development/web/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4091

Comment: @BrandonPowell I added more detail, which should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for @James Jones, I have one questions this might off topic but him getting and error message I tried to get_template_directory_uri() here screenshot --> https://gyazo.com/900cfec3172ff704f3ebd68ad141b913 That don't work so I don't know still learning lot so don't know lot about wp

Comment: @BrandonPowell recommend you create a new question for that problem